# django-disqus not using set_disqus_url or set_disqus_identifier

Tags: django, disqus

I have used an old version of https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus/ in the past. When I upgraded to 0.4, the new template tags, set_disqus_url and set_disqus_identifier, doesn't seem to work.

I guess `{% set_disqus_identifier "test" %}` should set `var disqus_identifier = 'test';` in the template, right?

Finally, I have followed the installation instruction, setting the SITE, api key and shortname. Putting `var disqus_identifier = 'test';` in the template works. 
So, could it be that django-disqus is broken?

EDIT: The developer of django-disqus told me that it is important to have these tags **in the same block** as `{% disqus_show_comments %}`, which of course is mentioned in the docs http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templatetags.html#disqus-show-comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solved but may be it is useful for someone else. Could it be that you forgot to load the disqus tags:

some_template.html

```
# load the tags
{% load disqus_tags %}
# get comments for your website
{% disqus_show_comments "YOUR_WEBSITE_SHORTNAME" %}
# get the url for the current object to get the right comments
{% set_disqus_url object.get_absolute_url %}
```